# How to display commit message along with blame command?

Tags: git

I have following command to show blame info for specific

`git blame -L 11,13 <file-path>`

But it won't give me the commit message, i have to run another command, may be `git show <hash>` to get the commit message.

The commit message is important here because i not need to know who did those changes, but why as well.

I tried `git log --date=iso -L 11,13:<file-path> --format="%h %an %ad %s"`, it seems good, but too many detail diff info displayed, and i don't need so many informations.

Below are what i required:

1. commit hash
2. author
3. author date
4. commit message
5. update content

Answer (score 3):

```
git blame -L 11,13 <file-path> | while read hash others;
do
    echo $hash $others "|Subject:" $(git log -1 --pretty=%s $hash)
done
```